# Calculating marginal and conditional probability distribution

Tags: machine-learning

The following is an example question from previous years of Machine Learning. Can anyone help me solve this question.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to solve part (a) involves marginalizing over all variables in the model.

`p(x3,x4)=1/Z \sum_{x1,x2,x5} \phi(x1,x2) \phi(x2,x4) \phi(x3,x4) \phi(x4,x5)`

`Z=\sum_{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5} \phi(x1,x2) \phi(x2,x4) \phi(x3,x4) \phi(x4,x5)`

In a small model like this, you can just compute the sums over the 2^3 and 2^5 respective possibilities. A better method, however, is to compute the sums using [belief propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation).

For instance, the sum in the numerator above can be rewritten as

`S(x4,x5)=\sum_{x1,x2,x5} \phi(x1,x2) \phi(x2,x4) \phi(x3,x4) \phi(x4,x5)`
`=\phi(x3,x4) \sum_{x5} \phi(x4,x5) \sum_{x2}  \phi(x2,x4) \sum_x1 \phi(x1,x2)`

The following intermediate sums can then be computed and used to obtain the final marginal probability:

`sx1x2(x2=0)=\phi(x1=0,x2=0)+\phi(x1=1,x2=0)`
`sx1x2(x2=1)=\phi(x1=0,x2=1)+\phi(x1=1,x2=1)`

`sx1x2x4(x4=0)=\phi(x2=0,x4=0) sx1x2(x2=0)+\phi(x2=1,x4=0) sx1x2(x2=1)`
`sx1x2x4(x4=1)=\phi(x2=0,x4=1) sx1x2(x2=0)+\phi(x2=1,x4=1) sx1x2(x2=1)`

`sx4x5(x4=0)=\phi(x4=0,x5=0)+\phi(x4=0,x5=1)`
`sx4x5(x4=1)=\phi(x4=1,x5=0)+\phi(x4=1,x5=1)`

Then

`S(x3,x4)=\phi(x3,x4) sx1x2x4(x4) sx4x5(x4)`

and

`Z=\sum_{x3,x4} S(x3,x4)`